# How do I pass a vector parameter to a map function without map iterating on it?

Tags: clojure

I currently have a CSV I'm trying to parse, which has headers and rows. I'm trying to map through the vector, but the map keeps iterating through the headers as opposed to the rows. Here is the code:

```
; csv is a lazyseq
; create-data-set takes two arguments: headers and row
(map (create-data-set (first csv) (rest csv))
```

How do I only iterate the last vector without affecting the former?

Comment: 1) You are missing a closing parenthesis. 2) What is the datatype of a "row" within `csv`? According to the comment `create-data-set` takes headers, plural and row, singular. Is that correct?

Comment: `(map (create-data-set (first csv)) (rest csv))` is more likely. and even then `create-data-set` would have to return a function. so maybe even `(map (partial create-data-set (first csv)) (rest csv))`.  but since we can guess that `csv` is a list of lists, it's hard to guess your `create-data-set`.

Comment: do you want this : `(map #(create-data-set (first csv) %1) (rest csv))`  it would call `create-data-set` (N-1) times where N is size of `csv`. each time it would pass `(first csv)` which i think might be header and new next row from the csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this (creating a new function to hold onto the headers, while mapping over the rows):

```
(map (partial create-data-set (first csv))
          (rest csv))
```

(I missed that this solution was present in a comment above -- apologies.)